# logstash output with document oriented elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

**First question about this topic** is with the code below, we can pass logstash output to elasticsearch. As you know, elasticsearch is document oriented. But the code below, we can only define an index not a document id. I want to ask that is it possible to define different document id for every logstash pipeline output ? If your answer is yes how, if not why ?

**Second question is**, if i run the code below. I have got yellow state in elasticsearch node. I know how to change it with manuely or sending dsl query via python etc. But is it possible to solve this inside of below code ?

```
elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "name_of_index" 
        http_compression => true
    }
```

**Thanks for answering..**

Comment: By "document name" do you mean "document id", i.e. the unique identifier of a given document?

Comment: Yes, I mean document id

Comment: Imagine that, I have a software that have large amount of logs and I want to pass that to elasticsearch with decomposing via date. So, my aim is having same index but so many documents to decomposed via date and if i run a "get query" to that document, i want to get only that day logs. Is it possible ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely specify the document ID using the [`document_id` setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-document_id):

```
elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "name_of_index-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    manage_template => true
    template_name => "my-template"
    template => "/path/to/my-template.json"
    document_id => "%{my_id_field}" 
    http_compression => true
}
```

You can also make sure that every day a new index is created by specifying the date pattern in the index name (see above).

Also make sure to have the following in a file called `my-template.json` that is referenced in the `elasticsearch` output. Its role is to provide the specific settings to use when creating your index. Here, since you have a single node, we're instructing the index to not create any replica shards, to make sure that the cluster will be green.

`my-template.json`

```
{
  "index_patterns": ["name_of_index*"],
  "template": {
    "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas": 0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this solved my question. But, one thing last, when i run the logstash config it sends the datas to elasticsearch its ok but how to solve yellow state ? I know manually solving this or sending dsl query via python etc. But is it possible to solve this inside of logstash elasticsearch output ?

Comment: Yes, but i can make more. But how should i define how many nodes i should?